# How Do I Force An Action When A Dialog Box Closes In VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

I am wondering how to force my main gui to update when a dialog box such as a `SaveFileDialog` box closes. I have tried `Main.LostFocus`, `Main.GotFocus`, `Main.Enter`, `Main.MouseEnter`, `Main.MouseLeave`, and `Main.MouseMove`, but no matter what function I try I can never get the result I am looking for.

The dialog box is opened when a picture is clicked. The picture changes when it is clicked and again when the `icon_new.MouseUp` is called. The problem is that it acts correctly until the dialog is closed. At this point the picture changes back to the image it had when the mouse was over it.

Here is what the picture does regularly:

```
Private Sub icon_new_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles icon_new.MouseDown
    icon_new.Image = My.Resources.NewMapClick
End Sub
Private Sub icon_new_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles icon_new.MouseUp
    icon_new.Image = My.Resources.NewMapHover
End Sub
Private Sub icon_new_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles icon_new.MouseEnter
    icon_new.Image = My.Resources.NewMapHover
End Sub
Private Sub icon_new_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles icon_new.MouseLeave
    icon_new.Image = My.Resources.NewMapDefault
End Sub
```

This works until the dialog box is closed, at which point it the image becomes `NewMapHover` when it should be `NewMapDefault`, because the mouse is no longer within the bounds of the picture. In the calls such as `Main.LostFocus`, `Main.GotFocus`, or `Main.Whatever` I have `icon_new.image = My.Resources.NewMapDefault`, but even if this call triggers, the image ends up as `NewMapHover`. I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is the click event that calls the dialog_box

```
Private Sub icon_new_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles icon_new.Click

    If file_created = True Then
        save()
    Else 'file_created = false'
        SaveWindow.FileName = txt_name.Text
        If SaveWindow.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            file_path = SaveWindow.FileName
        End If
        file_created = True
    End If
    save()
    new_file()

End Sub
```

If the file hasn't been saved, then a dialog box opens, prompting the user to save the file. I've also toyed with a `MsgBox()` that has Yes, No, and Cancel, prompts, but for simplicity I took it out because the results were the same and one third of the time the SaveFile dialog will come up anyway.

Comment: The dialog opens when mouse down, up or click? Do you have a mouse click event? Provide code.

Comment: Have you tried putting `icon_new.Image = My.Resources.NewMapDefault` as the first thing in your click event, before the dialog?

Comment: The MouseEnter/Leave events are pretty troublesome in general, you turn that trouble-dial to 11 when you do things like jerking the focus away with a dialog.

Comment: When you click the mouse the events are: *mouse_click -> mouse_up*. But in your mouse click you open a new window, so your form looses focus and a mouse leave event is driggered. The mouse up isnt triggerd yet. Is waiting until the dialog is closed. So you have *mouse_click -> mouse_leave -> (is waiting for dialog to close)mouse_up*

Comment: @ZeverMX Calling a modal dialog form means the mouse pointer isn't always over the originating control; the `MouseLeave` event only fires when the mouse pointer is *leaving* the control area, not when it is in an entirely new location.  Have you tried the same code in the `MouseUp` event?

Comment: @Steve Yes, I've tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: @valter I will try editing the MouseUp Event and see what I get. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you also for the suggestion on the MouseUp Event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I originally had.

```
Private Sub icon_new_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles icon_new.MouseUp
    icon_new.Image = My.Resources.NewMapHover
End Sub
```

I added the variable `dialog_open` as a `boolean` and set it to `true` whenever I called SaveFile.ShowDialog(). I then changed my MouseUp event to this:

```
Private Sub icon_new_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles icon_new.MouseUp
    icon_new.Image = My.Resources.NewMapHover
    If dialog_open = True Then
        icon_new.Image = My.Resources.NewMapDefault
        dialog_open = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks to @valter and @Kevin Hogg for suggesting I edit the MouseUp event.

Answer (score 0):

Try doubleclicking your SaveFileDialog, which will open up the SaveFileDialog_FileOk event code, and then put the same code there as in the MouseLeave event.

This event will fire when the SaveFileDialog is about to close after you've pressed the "Save" button.

---

EDIT:

You can try doing this in your click event:

```
Dim DResult As DialogResult
DResult = SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

If DResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    'Code for when you press the save button, and when the image should change
ElseIf DResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
    'Code for image change...
End If
```

Comment: The only problem with that is if the dialog is closed or cancel is clicked. I've tried putting the code in for when the result is cancel or save, in the click event that calls the dialog, but the result is still the same. In theory this should call the click event, then the dialog should be fully taken care of and off the stack, then the code to fix the image, but for some reason the final result is still incorrect. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was the first thing I tried. I'm sorry to say, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Private Sub icon_new_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles icon_new.MouseUp
    Dim pnt As Point
    Dim rect As Rectangle

    rect.X = icon_new.Location.X
    rect.Y = icon_new.Location.Y
    rect.Width = icon_new.Width
    rect.Height = icon_new.Height

    pnt = PointToClient(Cursor.Position)

    If Not rect.Contains(pnt) Then
        Return
    End If

    icon_new.Image = My.Resources.NewMapHover
End Sub
```

Valter

Comment: Thanks for your help. Editing the MouseUp event was the way to go, but I think I found a simpler way.